# How to provide authentication for mobile application in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic

I need to create a new web application along with the REST apis for mobile applications.I am planning to use Authlogic for authentication purpose. I want to know what is the best way to provide authentication for mobile devices? While searching I have found that we can authenticate mobile devices using access token, is their any plugin available for this or is it enough to generate an access token for each users  while login/registration  and make them to communicate with the web application with that access token in each request.

Answer (score 0):

Using devise gem you can generate authentication tokens.Based on this authentication tokens you can validate the userin mobile apps using REST api.We done this for android apps..

Comment: My app is currently using Authlogic I dont want to change it for this reason, is it enough to generate an access token for each users ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sub-module [Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::PersistenceToken](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/persistence_token.rb).